# Как засунуть if в условие for

Tags: java, массивы, if, for

Компилятор ругается, подскажите, пожалуйста, как засунуть if в for и можно ли вообще?

```
for (int i = 0; i <nums.length;  if (i < nums.length || i < nums[i].length) i += 1)
```

Comment: что хочешь сделать-то?

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i <nums.length;) if (i < nums.length || i < nums[i].length) i += 1;`

Comment: @Эникейщик
if внутри должен быть for ( ; ;if)

Comment: @Alexander Chernin

Comment: Ответ: нельзя. Если нужно какое-то хитрое условие для увеличения счетчика, то пишите его в теле for.

Comment: прям в задании написано "if должен быть внутри for"? Какова цель?

Comment: Узнать хотел, можно ли вообще. Оказалось нет @Эникейщик

Comment: в данном случае я бы использовал цикл while. Все-таки цикл for предполагает, что счетчик увеличивается с каждой итерацией, а здесь это не так, что плохо влияет на читаемость и понимаемость кода.

Comment: Уже так сделал, просто интересно было через for @Эникейщик

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В общем виде цикл `for` выглядит [так](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html):

```java
for (initialization; termination; increment) {
    statement(s)
}
```

Если у вас сложное выражение `increment`, то его можно написать в конце тела цикла:

```java
for (initialization; termination;) {
    statement(s)
    increment
}
```

Однако делать так не рекомендую, это ухудшает читаемость кода. Возможно вам нужно пересмотреть то, что вы делаете.

Answer (score 1):

Даже если это вдруг можно было бы сделать, то какой смысл? Посмотрим на условие:

```
if (i < nums.length || i < nums[i].length) i += 1
```

Первая его часть `i < nums.length` и так всегда истинна, потому что прописана в `for (int i = 0; i <nums.length; ...`, её вообще нет смысла проверять.
Вторая же часть если она вдруг **не** выполнится приведёт к тому, что на этой итерации `i` не увеличится и цикл просто "застрянет" на этом значении `i`. Правда, неизвестно, что вы делаете внутри цикла, может быть вы изменяете `nums[i]` внутри цикла, в этом случае просто поместите `if (i < nums[i].length) i += 1` внутрь тела цикла (в самый конец его) и всё.

Comment: for (int i = 0; i <nums.length;{ i += 1){
          for (int j = 0; j <nums[i].length; i += 1) там бы на втором застряло, но про первую часть спасибо